# Insert Into with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I new with PHP, MySQL and PDO.
With a lot of search, I made this piece of code to insert a new user/customer with a password.

```
<?php
require_once '../../src/mysql/dbconfig.php';

try
  {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    echo "Connected to $dbname at $host successfully.";
  } 
  catch (PDOException $pe) 
 {
   die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
 }

$stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$stmt -> bindValue(":email", $email);
$stmt -> bindValue(":password", $password);

$sql = "INSERT INTO customer (email, password) VALUES (:email, SHA2(:password,512))";

$stmt -> execute();
$conn = null;

?>

<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?><br>
Your password is: <?php echo $_POST["password"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

When I submit, go to another PHP page, say the user's email and password.
So when I do SELECT * FROM, I receive an empty SET.

(Basically, the Insert is not working, but on the PHP page, it says the information that was inserted in the INSERT)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: move the $sql up a few line, before the prepare statement

Answer (score -1):

Basically, what I was doing wrong was calling a statement after its values.

```
<?php
 require_once '../../src/mysql/dbconfig.php';

 try
 {
   $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
   echo "Connected to $dbname at $host successfully.";
 } 
 catch (PDOException $pe) 
{
 die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO customer (email, password) VALUES (:email,  SHA2(:password,512))";

 $stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $stmt -> bindValue(":email", $email);
 $stmt -> bindValue(":password", $password);

$stmt -> execute();
$conn = null;

?>
```